# Relative error and wobble

Tags: floating-point

The full context of the below is on page 8 of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/551.jvn.fall01/goldberg.pdf). In the below it is stated "In general, when the base is b, a fixed relative error expressed in ulps can wobble by a factor of up to b."

Can someone give a detailed proof of this? And what exactly does it mean by "a fixed relative error expressed in ulps can wobble by a factor of up to b."; if the relative error is *fixed* then how can it wobble or change?

> the relative error is always bounded by e, which is referred to as machine epsilon.
>
> ...
>
> To illustrate the difference between
> ulps and relative error, consider the real
> number x = 12.35. It is approximated
> by [image] = 1.24 x 10^1. The error is 0.5 ulps; the
> relative error is 0.8 e. Next consider the
> computation
> 8x. The exact value is 8 x =
> 98.8, whereas, the computed value is 8[image]
> = 9.92 x 10^1. The error is now 4.0 ulps,
> but the relative
> error is still 0.8 e. The
> error measured in ulps is eight times
> larger, even though the relative error is
> the same. In general, when the base is b,
> a fixed relative
> error expressed in ulps
> can wobble by a factor of up to b. Conversely, as eq. (2) shows, a fixed error of
> 1/2 ulps results in a relative error that
> can wobble by b.

Comment: This site is more about programming than the finer points of computer science. You're more likely to get a good answer on [math.se] or [cs.se]

Comment: Regarding your request for credible or official sources: The only person who can give you a more official answer is David Goldberg. The mathematics of this is absolute and clear, so the only issue is the phrasing and what the author was thinking. If it helps you accept my answer, purchase a copy of the IEEE 754-2008 floating-point standard [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4610935&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fstamp%2Fstamp.jsp%3Ftp%3D%26arnumber%3D4610935). On page vi, you will find my name, along with other committee members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is demonstrated on the same page as the quotes you give, in the paragraph before “In general, when the base is b, a fixed relative error expressed in ulps can wobble by a factor of up to b.”

That paragraph explains that numbers from 1.0000…0 • b<sup>e</sup> to d.dddd…d • b<sup>e</sup>, where d is, as I use it here, the digit b-1, have the same ULP, because the ULP is the value of the last digit, and that value of the last digit is determined by the exponent of b (and the number of digits in the significand, which is fixed for the format).

These numbers span a ratio of (almost) b, because d.dddd…d is almost b, so d.dddd…d / 1 is almost b. But they have the same ULP. Therefore, the magnitude of one ULP **relative** to the number spans a ratio of b.

#### Addressing the October 30, 2013, edit:

> And what exactly does it mean by "a fixed relative error expressed in ulps can wobble by a factor of up to b."; if the relative error is fixed then how can it wobble or change?

The error is said to be a fixed number of ULP. But the value of an ULP is not fixed or constant truly fixed or constant relative to floating-point values.

There is just a language issue here. It is not accurate to speak of an ULP as a “fixed relative error”. However, people sometimes express error bounds or error amounts in ULPs because the nature of floating-point quantizes values, and those quanta are ULPs.

ULP is **approximately** a relative error. It stays in the same range throughout the entire scale of a floating-point format. Consider a three-digit decimal format:

- In the interval from 1.00 to 9.99, the absolute value of the ULP is .005. Its value relative to numbers in the interval ranges from .005 to (almost) .0005.
- In the interval from 1,000,000 to 9,990,000, the absolute value of the ULP is 5,000. Its value relative to numbers in the interval ranges from .005 to (almost) .0005.
- In the interval from 1.00•10<sup>-100</sup> to 9.99•10<sup>-100</sup>, the absolute value of the ULP is .005•10<sup>-100</sup>. Its value relative to numbers in the interval ranges from .005 to (almost) .0005.

As you see, the value of the ULP relative to floating-point numbers always stays within a small interval. Thus, it serves as an approximation of a relative error.

The fact that **our expressions of** relative errors in floating-point arithmetic wobble by a factor of b comes from two mathematical facts:

- When you work with floating-point arithmetic and calculate or derive a proof about the errors that may occur, you will find yourself expressing errors in units of ULP, because the quantization of the floating-point format causes bounds to be in ULPs or half-ULPs.
- For floating-point values x, the value of an ULP of x divided by x changes by a factor of b as x changes **within a single exponent interval** of the floating-point format. When the exponent changes, the value ULP(x)/x resets.

Comment: I stil don't understand how to interpret the quote but consider this thought. The relative error of x and the fp number y is (x-y)/x and  multiply by m where m is 2,3,...,or b-1 gives the relative error of m*x and m*y which is still (x-y)/x but the absolute error changes by m. This is true even if m is greater than or equal to b. But then y and m*y will be in regions with different ULP for sure. So is the quote suppose to mean "a fixed relative error results in an absolute error expressed in ulps that can wobble up to b"?

Comment: In the above do I allow m=b to get "wobble up to b" instead of "wobble up to b-1". And should making sense of m being real be allowed too?

Comment: When you say absolute value of a ULP, you mean the max. absolute error when approximating a real number with the FP number right? So when you approximate 1.005 with 1.00, you get (1.005 - 1.00) = 0.005.

Comment: @PrashantPandey: “Absolute value of an ULP” is used in this answer to distinguish it from considering it as a ratio to the numbers in an interval.

Comment: @PrashantPandey: When we convert a real number to a floating-point number, the conversion has some error because the original real number is not representable in the floating-point conversion. The result of the conversion is a specific number with some error from the desired number. Except for overflow, the maximum value of this error is ½ ULP, because 1 ULP is the distance between representable numbers and any number in between two representable numbers is at most ½ ULP away from one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post and there was already an excellent answer from an expert in this field. I will try to answer this question from a different viewpoint since I had the same question as OP when I read David Goldberg's paper:

If the relative error E between a real number x and its floating point number representation y is fixed, the only way to change A and B is by multiplying them with another number c which can be accurately expressed on the computer, e.g., an integer (but not another real number since expressing it as another floating point number to multiply y will incur rounding error and change the relative error).

E=(|x-y|)/|x|=constant=(|c*x-c*y|)/|c*x|

The cited text gives one example of c = 8, but actually, c can be any integer value. The wobble magnitude b then comes from the differences between cases in which you choose c to be 1 or b-1. In addition, if you choose c to be b, it just returns to the case of c being 1 by increasing the exponent of b by 1. Then, choosing any c larger than b is equal to choosing c mod b.